# What is the path for a file inside converted .exe file?

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

I use Launch4J for convert my .jar file to .exe. My application have language files inside jar.

Example:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/me/s3ns3iw00/resources/languages/ENG.properties");
```

If the application is in .jar format, the jarpath is correct, but if I convert the jar to exe, my application can't find the file inside 'jar'.

What is the correct path to that file in exe format?

Thanks for help, and sorry for my bad english!

**EDIT**
The application find the files, but I can't read the properties file inside exe.

Comment: Are the resources packaged into your jar? If all is in the jar conversion to exe should not make a difference.

Comment: Of course! But the application can't find the file in the exe.

Comment: Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: not an answer, but is there any specific reason you package your jar into an exe? it defeats one of the main advantages of java, cross-platform-compatibility

Comment: No exceptions. Oh I didn't know it would be incompatible.